# ChunkLoadError accessing local file while application idles overnight

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have an issue with an Electron app (19.x) built with React (18).

One of my testers, when leaving the application running overnight, will occasionally return in the morning to a new blank Electron window and the following in its devtools console:

```
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 3495 failed.              react-dom.production.min.js:189
(timeout: file://C:/Users/<rest of filepath to chunk inside app.asar>)
```

The stacktrace resolves back to a line such as this:

```
const SystemOutagePage = lazy(() => import('src/pages/systemOutage'));
```

which in normal operation is triggered when the application loses connectivity with various backend services. So the window opening is expected (e.g. if the users home router reboots overnight), but the failure to load the local outage page is not.

My question is: What could be causing this chunk load timeout error?

Some notes:

- The path of the module it is trying to lazy load is a local filesystem file.
- The chunk filepath it is trying to access is valid - the application's files are deployed (and replaced) in their entirety during app installation/update.
- The system outage page works correctly when tested. This issue so far has affected only one user, and only when they leave the application running overnight.

Comment: How do you know this: **The chunk filepath it is trying to access is valid**? Have you confirmed the chunk was available from the origin server at the time of request? Perhaps the affected user had an old manifest loaded while the kept the app open and you pushed a new build to the origin server (or however you serve static assets).

Comment: As mentioned in the description (by the file:// path) and the notes, the chunk file it is trying to load is on the local filesystem - not an origin server. They are all bundled as part of the app.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is likely related to the user's system being a laptop and going into hibernation overnight. It appears the process of suspension/unsuspension is problematic for the app.

The issue is likely resolved by use of Electron's powerSaveBlocker API to prevent the OS from suspending the application while its in use. I'll update and accept this answer if the solution holds.